# Netsuite Suitelet Script Upload: Chinese Characters Turn into Garbled Text

Tags: visual-studio-code, utf-8, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm currently working on a Suitelet script in NetSuite, and my work environment requires displaying Chinese characters. I'm using VSCode as my IDE and have confirmed that the encoding is set to UTF-8 (displayed in the bottom-right corner). The Chinese characters appear correctly in the editor.

However, when I upload the file to NetSuite's File Cabinet and view the JavaScript file, all the Chinese characters turn into garbled text. This issue only occurs after uploading; the characters are displayed correctly in VSCode.

Is this a problem with my environment settings, or am I missing some necessary configurations when uploading files to NetSuite?

```
var form = serverWidget.createForm({ title: "多筆列印傳票" });


var form = serverWidget.createForm({ title: "螟夂ｭ?蛻怜魂蛯ｳ逾ｨ" });
```

[image: upload file]

[image: preview file]

[image: after upload file in netsuite]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I will add images to it. It seems that this issue is not related to the program code. I have tested it, and even with a txt file, as long as it contains Chinese characters, after uploading to the NetSuite file cabinet, it turns into gibberish. I suspect this has to do with the settings of the NetSuite environment I am using.

Comment: I'm developing in two different NetSuite environments and observing differing behaviors with the same code upload. My environments are 'NetSuite (Version: Japan)' and 'NetSuite (Version: United States)'. This leads me to suspect the issue might be related to the specific environment settings. As a NetSuite newcomer without senior developer support, I'm cautious about altering the company's NetSuite version settings.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `"多筆列印傳票".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp932', 'replace')` returns `'螟夂ｭ�蛻怜魂蛯ｳ逾ｨ'`. (Any of `['shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004', 'shift_jisx0213']` encoding in `'cp932'` place…)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on what you've mentioned, it seems that if the NetSuite system version is set to Japan, it might default to using the CP932 encoding. This could be why my documents, which are in UTF-8 format, are showing garbled Chinese characters when uploaded.

Comment: Assuming my assumption is correct, based on your experience, would you recommend that I change the encoding format I'm using, or should I modify my NetSuite environment to better support UTF-8

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…